# Permissions in memory or in database

Tags: permissions, authorization, nestjs, rbac, abac

I’m doing a project where we essentially decided to go with ABAC (attribute based access control) and when designing the middleware and database i had this question stuck in my head, why do we store permissions?

If I’m going to need the permissions in memory which is how I’ll be implementing the middleware, for example user needs write permission for a certain resource, then what’s the point of keeping a Permissions table?

Comment: Do you expect your application to always be available in memory? No crashes, no need for re-deployments, etc?

Comment: Well no, even if i'm only keeping my permissions in memory i'm still aiming towards using the database so i don't really need it to work without the db. My question though is how would i do that, how would i write middlewares for authorization without referencing the permissions in memory. Because if i have a permissions table where i set let's say a write permission to the books resource how would i avoid writing the same permission and resource in my code as well?